# I have 2 sql join queries here that returns null and returns same service name. my question is what part of the sql query i did wrong

Tags: mysql

I want to get the assign_id, mass_fname, mass_lname, service_name, assign_start, assign_end

tbl_masseur

```
mass_id 
mass_fname  
mass_lname  
mass_contact    
mass_address
```

tbl_assigndetails

```
assign_id   
service_id  
assign_start    
assign_end
```

tbl_assignment

```
assign_id   
mass_id 
assign_date 
assign_gtotal
```

tbl_services

```
service_id  
service_name    
service_description 
service_price
```

[Query that returns null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2RNG.png)

[Query that returns same service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYGBr.png)

```
SELECT tbl_assigndetails.assign_id, tbl_assignment.assign_id,
        tbl_masseur.mass_id,tbl_masseur.mass_fname, tbl_masseur.mass_lname, 
        tbl_assignment.assign_date, tbl_services.service_name,
        tbl_assigndetails.assign_start,tbl_assigndetails.assign_end 
FROM tbl_assigndetails 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_assignment ON tbl_assigndetails.assign_id = tbl_assignment.assign_id 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_services ON tbl_assigndetails.service_id = tbl_services.service_id 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_masseur on tbl_assignment.mass_id=tbl_masseur.mass_id
```

this query return same service name

```
SELECT tbl_assigndetails.assign_id, tbl_assignment.assign_id,   
        tbl_masseur.mass_id,tbl_masseur.mass_fname, 
        tbl_masseur.mass_lname, tbl_assignment.assign_date, 
        tbl_services.service_name,tbl_assigndetails.assign_start,
        tbl_assigndetails.assign_end
FROM tbl_assignment
    LEFT JOIN tbl_assigndetails ON tbl_assignment.assign_id = tbl_assigndetails.assign_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_services ON tbl_assignment.assign_id = tbl_services.service_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_masseur on tbl_assignment.mass_id=tbl_masseur.mass_id
```

this query return null

I cant really understand well the concept of joins.

Answer (score 0):

Try below SQL query:

```
select tbl_assignment.assign_id, tbl_masseur.mass_fname, tbl_masseur.mass_lname, tbl_services.service_name, tbl_assigndetails.assign_start, tbl_assigndetails.assign_end 
from tbl_masseur 
left join tbl_assignment on tbl_assignment.mass_id=tbl_masseur.mass_id 
left join tbl_assigndetails on tbl_assigndetails.assign_id=tbl_assignment.assign_id 
left join tbl_services on tbl_services.service_id=tbl_assigndetails.service_id
```